# Characters per line and font size

Tags: fontsize, opentype, truetype

Can i automatically change font size to get desired (66) "Characters per line" value?

I do not want to change magins size or textwidth, only font size.

Alternatively i'm looking for a macro which display number of characters on margin. For debugging/hand tunin purposes.

Answer (score 2):

#### 2.5 alphabets

While the 66-character/per line is a common ideal setting, you cannot lock it to that, as the characters used have varying widths, especially when considering various different languages. A different approach is to measure the width of a lowercase alphabet for a given language, `abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz` in English, and set the textwidth to about 2.5 times this.

The information is paraphrased for *The Elements of Typographic Style* by *Robert Bringhurst*.

In the code below, edit the alphabet to language you are using.

#### Output

[image]

#### Code

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\newcommand{\alphabet}{%
  abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz%
}
\newlength{\textW}
\setlength{\textW}{\widthof{\alphabet}* \real{2.5}}
\geometry{textwidth=\textW,}

\begin{document}

\Blindtext

\end{document}
```